# $(1-z^n)^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-\epsilon(n)^kz)^{-1},~\epsilon(n) = \exp(-2\pi i/n)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on a functional analysis problem and it would be very helpful to prove that
$$(1-z^n)^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-\epsilon(n)^kz)^{-1},~\epsilon(n) = \exp(-2\pi i/n),~z : |z| < 1.$$

I tried the naive approach by induction, but could not follow. I do appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, of course, that all complex $n$-th roots of $1$ are of the form $\epsilon(n)^{-k}=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$, $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, according to your notation, hence $$z^n-1=\prod^{n-1}_{j=0}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})=\prod^{n-1}_{j=0}\epsilon(n)^{-j}(\epsilon(n)^j z-1)$$ so that $$\frac{1}{1-\epsilon(n)^k z}=\epsilon(n)^{-k}\frac{\prod^{n-1}_{j=0 \atop j\neq k}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})}{1-z^n}\ ,\quad k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$$ and therefore $$\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{1}{1-\epsilon(n)^k z}=\frac{1}{1-z^n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\epsilon(n)^{-k}\prod^{n-1}_{j=0 \atop j\neq k}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})\ .$$ This means we are done if we can show that $$\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\epsilon(n)^{-k}\prod^{n-1}_{j=0 \atop j\neq k}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})=n\ .$$ However, we know that $$\epsilon(n)^{-k}\prod^{n-1}_{j=0 \atop j\neq k}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})=z\prod^{n-1}_{j=0 \atop j\neq k}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})-(z^n-1)\ ,\quad k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$$ and hence $$\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\epsilon(n)^{-k}\prod^{n-1}_{j=0 \atop j\neq k}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})=z\left[\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\prod^{n-1}_{j=0 \atop j\neq k}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})-nz^{n-1}\right]+n\ ,$$ but differentiating both sides of the first identity above with respect to $z$ yields $$\frac{d}{dz}(z^n-1)=nz^{n-1}=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\prod^{n-1}_{j=0}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})\right)=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\prod^{n-1}_{j=0 \atop j\neq k}(z-\epsilon(n)^{-j})$$ and hence the term between square brackets above is zero as we wished, thus leading to the desired identity.

Comment: this is the clever solution I was told. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is the partial fraction expansion of the left-hand side. To verify it, it suffices to show that the two sides have the same poles—that is, for any $0\le k\le n-1$, to show that when you multiply both sides by $1-\epsilon(n)^k z$, the two resulting expressions have the same limit as $z\to\epsilon(n)^{-k}$.

Comment: Thank you. A friend came out with a very clever solution. If no one comes to that, I will accept your answer.